# Using UISegmentedControl to Change the Data of Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app, there will be actually two table view but they will not really different from each other. The only difference between two view is the URL they have, because I update my table with the data coming from the URL. Everything other than URL remains same. I used to have 2 different view controller and switch between them, but later I thought having one Table View Controller and just change the URL and update the table with the given URL is a better idea.

I came up with this:

[image]

And below there is a part of my `viewDidLoad` function in table, where I take the data from URL (I'm using AFNetworking):

[image]

Problem I'm having here is, it doesn't reload the data; although I use reloadData method of the table. Shortly, I switch but nothing happens.

What am I missing do you think? Or the way I thought is wrong from the beginning?

For convenience, here is the storyboard I have, it is simple :)

[image]

Comment: Can you give us details on how the tableView accesses viewController.URL?

Comment: Your "Table View Controller" is type of UITableViewController or UIViewController? If its UITableViewController than you can directly reload data using [self.viewController reloadData]; if its UIViewController and you have taken UITableView in that. Make sure you have set datasource and delegate properly.

Comment: Added as you asked. And my table view controller is taken actually a view controller and I took tableview into that controller. I'm sure of datasource and delegate, because they were working before I tried to change segmented controller.

Comment: Is your tableview updated when url fetches data from server, I see that it calls updateGoldArrayWithDictionary: method. Is that method reloads your tableview after fetching data? And yes, you should create new method which used fetch data when url is changed. and call that method from segment change method.

Comment: Yes at first it reloads. So app starts with a data, but it doesn't change when I try to change. So what you suggest is same with uros19, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. By default a `UITableViewController`'s `dataSource` is set to `self` (ie the `UITableViewController` is the data source, which is why it has all those `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods).

What you could do instead is move all those methods to your own class, `MyDataSource`, then on init:

```
self.dovizDataSource = [[MyDataSource alloc] initWithURL:<dovizURL>];
self.altinDataSource = [[MyDataSource alloc] initWithURL:<altinURL>];
```

When you want to switch, set

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self.dovizDataSource;
```

or

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self.altinDataSource;
```

then

```
self.tableView reloadData;
```

See [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW67) docs, [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) protocol reference.

Comment: I see. Just a quick question, what does myDataSource refers in my case?

Comment: It's a new class that you create. It should be a subclass of `NSObject`, and it should conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, and all your existing `UITableViewDataSource` methods should be moved out of the table's view controller and into the new `MyDataSource` class.

Answer (score 1):

### First problem here:

```
self.viewController = [self.storyboard instanciateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableView"];
```

You instantiate manually your view controller. The storyboard already manages this allocation for you, so after your `viewDidLoad`, you have your TableView displayed by the system with no reference to it, and you have a reference to another TableView not displayed.

Instead, remove the line I mentioned above and catch the view controller when it's instantiated by the system, in `prepareForSegue`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
}
```

You should name your segue by clicking on it and change the identifier in the attribute inspector, in case you have several segues in your viewController. You can get their name with `segue.identifier` and do actions depending on.

### Second: I don't see any code that reloads your data

You may want to recall `APIClient GetInformationFrom:self.URL…` and in the completion block call `[self.viewController.tableView reloadData]` to make sure you have your new data before reloading.

Comment: So you think, just that will be enough ? I'll give it a try and back to you

Comment: Didn't work. I think what I've missed was your correction, but I still needed the others suggestion.

Comment: I saw this first in your code so I think it probably won't help you. Also, changing your URL is not quite much. I dont' see code that fetch the URL after changing it. I'm editing my response.